# Creating a class-based reusable application

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins, python-2.x, code-reuse

I am trying to create a re-usable application in python 2.6.

I am developing server-side scripts for listening GPS tracking devices. The script are using sockets.

I have a base class that defines the basic methods for handling the data sent by device.

```python
class MyDevice(object):
    def __init__(self, db)
        self.db = db  # This is the class that defines methods for connecting/using database

    def initialize_db(self):
        ...

    def handle_data(self):
        self.initialize_db()
        ...
        self.process_data()

    def process_data(self):
        ...
        self.categorize_data()

    def categorize_data(self):
        ...
        self.save_data()

    def save_data(self):
        ...
```

This base class serves for many devices since there are only some minor differences between the devices. So I create a class for each *specific* device type and make arrangements which are specific to that device.

```python
class MyDeviceType1(Mydevice):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(MyDeviceType1, self).__init__(db)

    def categorize_data(self):
        super(MyDeviceType1, self).categorize_data(self)
        self.prepopulate_data()
        ...  # Do other operations specific to device

    def prepopulate_data(self):
        """this is specific to Type1 devices"""
        ...


class MyDeviceType2(Mydevice):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(MyDeviceType1, self).__init__(db)

    def categorize_data(self):
        super(MyDeviceType1, self).categorize_data(self)
        self.unpopulate_data()
        ...  # Do other operations specific to device

    def unpopulate_data(self):
        """this is specific to Type2 devices"""
        ...
```

And I have socket listeners that listens specific sockets, and call related class (`MyDeviceType1` or `MyDeviceType2`) like:

```python
conn, address = socket.accept()
...
thread.start_new_thread(MyDeviceType1(db_connector).handle_data, ())
```

That structure is all fine and useful to me. One device (*MyDevice*) may have many subtypes (*MyDeviceType1*, *MyDeviceType2*) which inherits the base class.

And there are more than one type of base devices. So there is *OtherDevice* with subtypes *OtherDeviceType1* etc.

`MyDevice` and `OtherDevice` works quite differently, so they are the base types and underlying code is quite different in all of them.

I also have some add-on functionalities. These functionalities are usable by one or two subtypes of nearly all device base types.

So I want to prepare a single reusable (plug-able) class that can be inherited by any subtype that needs those functionalities.

```python
class MyAddOn(object):
    def remove_unusable_data(self):
       ...

    def categorize_data(self):
        super ???
        self.remove_unusable_data()
```

And here is the part that I stuck. Since this is an independent module, it should not be inherited from `MyDevice` or `OtherDevice` etc, but not all sub device types are using these functionalities, I can not inherit `MyDevice` from `MyAddOn` too.

Only logical method looks like, inheriting the subtype `MyDeviceSubType1` from both `MyDevice` and `MyAddOn`

```python
class MyDeviceType1(Mydevice, MyAddOn):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(MyDeviceType1, self).__init__(db)

    def categorize_data(self):
        >> super(MyDeviceType1, self).categorize_data(self) <<
        self.prepopulate_data()
        ...  # Do other operations specific to device

    def prepopulate_data(self):
        """this is specific to Type1 devices"""
```

`super(MyDeviceType1, self).categorize_data(self)` is the problem part. `super` is triggering the `Mydevice.categorize_data` but not `MyAddOn.categorize_data`

Is there any way to trigger `MyAddOn` methods using `super` call or in a such fashion that I do not need to call that class method seperately? Both `MyDevice.categorize_data` and `MyAddOn.categorize_data` should be called.

Comment: Why does this added functionality have to be "plug-able"? 
It looks like your addon operates on some data that can be acquired by a device and is more of a utility function that does a transformation. If this doesn't require any state of the device, why bother forcing this utility functionality onto the device? Get the data from a device and pass it to the utility function.

Comment: If the op wants the thing to be extendable by others, classes beat utility functions. If the op publishes the library on pypi, anyone can reuse the code and override the parts they don't like.

Answer (score 2):

This is called cooperative multiple inheritance in python and works just fine.

What you refer to as an "Addon" class, is generally called a "Mixin".

Just call the `super` method in your Mixin class:

```
class MyAddOn(object):
    def remove_unusable_data(self):
       ...

    def categorize_data(self):
        super(MyAddon,self).categorize_data()
        self.remove_unusable_data()
```

I'd like to note some things:

- The method resolution order is left to right
- You have to call super
- You should be using **kwargs for cooperative inheritance

---

It seems counterintuitive to call `super` here, as the parent of `MyAddon` does not have an attribute called `categorize_data`, and you would expect this notation to fail.

This is where the `super` function comes into play. [Some](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) consider this behaviour to be the best thing about python.

Unlike in *C++* or *Java* the `super` function does not necessarily call the class' parent class. In fact it is impossible to know in advance which function will be called by `super` because it will be decided at run-time based on the [method resoltion order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

`super` in python should really be called `next` because it will call the next method in the inheritance tree.

For Mixins it is especially important to call super, even if you're inheriting from `object`.

For further information I advise to watch Raymond Hettinger's excellent talk on [Super considered Super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) from pycon 2015.

---

It's an excellent pattern to use in python. Here is a pattern I encounter often when programming structured applications obeying the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle):

I have this library class which is used in production:

```
class BaseClassA(object):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       ... Do something that's important for many modules
   def ...   

class BaseClassB(object):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       ... Do something that's important for many modules
   def ...
```

Now you get a feature request that in a particular case both `BaseClassA` and `BaseClassB` should implement feature X.

According to open-close you shouldn't have to touch existing code to implement the feature, and according to DRY you shouldnt repeat the code.

The solution is to create a `FeatureMixin` and create empty child classes which inherit from the base class and the mixin:

```
class FeatureMixin(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        ...do something specific
        return super(FeatureMixin,self).__init__(**kwargs)
class ExtendedA(FeatureMixin,BaseClassA):
   pass
class ExtendedB(FeatureMixin,BaseClassB):
   pass
```